# Execute python file in Laravel and save data into DB

Tags: python, laravel, database

I have a python script that I want to execute in my Laravel application through the pressure of a button and then save in a DB some data that returns me the script.
I use symfony/process but I don't get the desired result.
Someone can help me?

My view in Laravel is this:

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/scan') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ghost-primary" id="scan">Scan Device</button><br>
</form>
```

The controller is this:

```
public function scan()
    {
        $process = new Process(['python', 'C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py']);
        $process->run();
        $process->getOutput();
    }
```

And the Route is:

```
Route::post('scan', [DataFromRaspController::class, 'scan'])->name('scan');
```

Comment: do you try to return or dump output?
please try dd($process->getOutput());
abd send a screenshot of your response to me.

Comment: Hi @kousha ghodsizad
This is the screenshot

https://imgur.com/a/oUXFmgh

Comment: use code and see what is going on, if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahAlFarooq the error that results is: 

The command "'python' 'C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /var/www/html/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: 1: exec: python: not found

Comment: You are welcome @Max. I also wrote it in answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot your problem, please check the exception. By default, it doesn't show any underlying errors.

```python
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

Don't forget to include,

```
 use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

Comment: Thanks, the error that results is: The command "'python' 'C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /var/www/html/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: 1: exec: python: not found

Comment: @Max, if you accept it as an answer then please mark it as an answer.

Comment: By the way, as you are in windows, then make sure you are providing the full python executable path. @Max

Comment: A better way would be to include the python executable path in your windows PATH environment variable and write the process name as 'python.exe'. Though I have not tested it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to include python exe in windows PATH...many thanks @Abdullah Al Farooq